# How to solve open weather lat lon Problem?

Tags: android, sdk

**This is my url.**

https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=23.8103&lon=90.4125&cnt=10&appid=ab1f919d021e76086bbdf2761777438d

when I change lat and lon but data is not changing. it showing same temp and location.

Comment: That's a sample URL...

Comment: yes, but if use api.openweathermap..... it showing  "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info.

Comment: how can i solve it ?

Comment: You need to get an API key. You can't just use the sample.

Comment: yes, I got an API, its work. thank you brother